# Token authentication with rest backend secure enough

Tags: authentication, playframework, ionic-framework

I would like to secure my mobile app ( hybrid app, build with ionic framework). On backend site I use the play framework. I would implement the following case. The user of the app should authenticate to rest backend by email and password, if the credentials correct the backend generates an token return ok with the generate token to client, otherwise the backend return bad request. If the user would try to login with incorrect credentials more then 10 times the user would deactivated for 1 hour.
The mobile app would load json data from backend with ajax calls, on each call in header would set the field 'X-AUTH-TOKEN' and the generate token. The backend check the token and if the token is correct the client get data from server with status ok else the client get none data and the status unauthorized. If the user logged out the token would destroyed on server and client side. The token would not change as long as the user is logged in, in worst case the token would not changed over more than many days. I could implement, that on each call the date of last call can saved and if the last call is more than x days in past the server return unauthorized and destroy the token. So the user should logged in.  Is the case secure enough, or should I implement more logic?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is very similar, if not identical to the many, many implementations of OAuth2. For more information on these types of flows, including diagrams, check out how Google describes their OAuth2 processes here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

I'm not familiar with the play framework but you should speak with framework experts to see if there is a well-tested, battle-hardened oauth2 implementation out there for the Play Framework. If so, you want to use that. You really don't want to (and shouldn't) roll your own implementation unless you know what you're doing and are willing to pay for people to pentest it. Really, please don't do this if unsure.

On the Ionic Framework / Angular / Cordova side, you've basically got it correct, but should always consider some basic security considerations:

My guess is that you'd use local storage to store the access token. In REST we don't have sessions like in a traditional web server scenario so we use the token in lieu of the session.  Of course the downside is that local storage can easily be inspected to obtain the access key if someone had either root access on the device and was able to work their way into the app sandbox and knew exactly what api key to grab from local storage, but if someone has root or physical access to the device then you've got a bigger problem, so this isn't a design flaw per-say. To a certain extent, using this method you're relying upon the OS/browser's local storage sandbox to prevent other apps from accessing the local storage in your ionic app. This is a bet I would be willing to make, but you'll need to judge that based on your security vs usability needs.

What you should really be focusing on is protecting the token from people who may be listening on the wire (think coffee shop wifi). This means setting up your auth rest servers to use exclusively HTTPS (don't fail back to HTTP). This may have downsides, but will be worth it to protect your user's data. You also correctly identified using the token header. You should never pass auth tokens in anything but the header or POST data.

Generally speaking, what you are describing should be safe for use in a consumer level app. This assumes you don't unwittingly use any malicious third party code in your app.  As always, you should be especially wary of third party code and only use code that you absolutely trust. Any code run from inside your app can access local storage in the Cordova/browser local storage sandbox and could theoretically export the api token for use in other software to access your api. With that said, you asked about authentication and not authorization. Keep in mind that your users need to only have access to do certain things in the app based on user-roles or some sort of ACL. This authorization outside the scope of this answer but you need to ensure that this is done on the server side and has rate limiting or soft-deletes for shared resources to prevent a malicious user from deleting everything.

Good luck with ionic and have fun.